# Верно ли, что при создании таблицы в YDB лучше все столбцы создавать NULLABLE?

Tags: ydb

Правда ли, что при создании таблицы в YDB нужно делать все столбцы NULLABLE?

Answer (score 0):

Так было в старых версиях. Сейчас YDB поддерживает NOT NULL для столбцов первичного ключа и рекомендуется в первичном ключе NULL-ы запрещать.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id INT64 NOT NULL,
    second INT64,
    val INT64,
```